# Android: Get touch outside of Floating Window

Tags: java, android, touch

I want to close a View in an Floating window when the Touchscreen is touched outside of this floating window and I haven't found a way to get that touch Event.

Comment: what do you mean by floating window? are you talking about dialog and alert boxes? or some custom component? please share a complete problem with what you've tried so far to resolve your problem

Comment: I mean a Floating Widget, sorry I thought it was called Floating Window.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your theme:

```
 <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
```

Also, check this [article](http://cases.azoft.com/android-tutorial-floating-activity/), it might help.

Comment: I think setOutsideTouchable(true) only works with Popup Windows but my View is an Floating Widget. Is it Possible to set this option on an Floating Widget?